# How to retrieve company Elasticsearch data from Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am very new to Elasticsearch and want to analyze data in python.
I installed Elasticsearch `pip` and tried to import data but failed with error messages

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'hosts':'10.251.0.135', 'port':'5601'}])
es.info()
```

```
> ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD21943460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD21943460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]

or

    es = Elasticsearch("http://10.251.0.134:5601/")
    es.info()

> TransportError: TransportError(302, '')
```

I looked out some solutions but they kinda assume that I have Elasticsearch in my local machine, which in my case isn't much helpful.

I don't think I am not authorized to access the data as I can access to data through web-hosting Kibana app. Hope to know what would be the problem.

Comment: The port `5601` is the Kibana port, not the elasticsearch, the python library needs to connect directly to elasticsearch, which per default uses port `9200`, try to change the port to `9200` and see if you can connect.

Comment: Thank for the hint! Just tried now and... still got another error message :/

 ConnectionError: ConnectionError((<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD2430DCA0>, 'Connection to 10.251.0.135 timed out. (connect timeout=10)')) caused by: ConnectTimeoutError((<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AD2430DCA0>, 'Connection to 10.251.0.135 timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

I don't think es.info() is that much heavy enough to make connection timeout error.

Comment: Could be a connection issue, can you access `10.251.0.135:9200` on the browser? If not,  then you will need to check your elasticsearch configuration. Update your question with your `elasticsearch.yml`, it could be listening only on localhost, or maybe you have a firewall blocking the direct access to elasticsearch, you need to check that also.

Comment: ohhh thank you for the comment! requested firewall blocking disable and it works... you shed light on me thank you leandrojmp :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to leandrojmp, I manage to find the answer.

My situation was:

At work, needed to retrieve Elasticsearch server data to python.
I was the only analyst and others see data through kibana(5601).
No Elasticsearch or Kibana installed on my local machine, so the advice like change configuration doesn't seems to match.
The error was as stated on the question

How I manage to figure out:

I went to port 9200 on the browser, which is direct access to Elasticsearch DB and find out that I only have access to port 5601, not 9200.
Asked Server manager to disable the firewall, and everything works find :)